# Excel crashing with large spreadsheets

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have about 1000 rows x 16 columns of data. None of it is formatted but it is being used in 2 graphs. If I click one thing excel will crash for 10 seconds.

My PC should be plenty powerful enough for this (i7 9700k, 16GB ram, ssd) and I'm running 64bit Excel. It's only using 5% of CPU and around 600MB of ram. I don't have any addons running and I've checked for updates.

Is Excel just not optimised for this kind of task?

Comment: 16,000 cells is absolutely nothing.    So the crashing must be due to the content of the cells.  So what are the contents of those cells?

Comment: If you are using Excel 2007 or above try disabling Hardware Graphics Acceleration in File ->Options ->Advanced -> Display settings

Comment: try to switch the calculation mode in excel from automatic to manual [ "Formula" > Calculation > Manual.  ] , then load the file..

Comment: Only one Workbook have this problem? Try to copy the data to a new Workbook and check if it works.